# CSS: max-width for @media query not working

Tags: html, css, media-queries

(It works on other browsers but not chrome)

I want to apply a style only when the browser size is less than 1400px

with `max-width` not working

```
@media only screen and (max-width:1400px)  {
.heading-left {
    left: -0.5%;
  }
}
```

with `min-width` its working

```
@media only screen and (min-width:480px)  {
.heading-left {
    left: -0.5%;
   }
}
```

But also alters when browser width is above 1400px (I know thats how it works but max-width is not working)

Fiddle for this

https://jsfiddle.net/j4Laddtk/

Comment: Could be you have the queries in the wrong order...but without a demo it;s hard to help.

Comment: This is the only media query right now

Comment: can you provide a fiddle?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/j4Laddtk/

Comment: the developer tool was saying that the size of the viewport is 1400px but the actual width the css was considering was more than 1400px. Because of this the media query isn't working.

Comment: @DivyaBarsode did u got any solution? me too facing the same issue.

Comment: @Logeshwaran I didn't find any solution. Just did trial and error and used those values

Comment: @Logeshwaran, sure. sent invite

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Media Queries firing at wrong width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26696254/media-queries-firing-at-wrong-width)

Answer (score 169):

Have you tried adding the viewport in?

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

[Working JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j4Laddtk/1/)

Viewport is used when rendering responsive pages and is therefore mostly used when dealing with mobile websites, but when dealing with media queries it helps tell the CSS what the actual device-width is.

Comment: Without this tag, media queries just MATCH regardless of the condition. e.g. max-width: x px always returns true.

Answer (score 51):

Is your **browser** `zoom`-ed at different than `100%` level ? If so, zoom to `100%` (`Ctrl+MouseWheel`)

Comment: I spent at least half an hour on this.  You are a gentle(wo)man and a scholar!

Comment: You saved my life. Checked all the technical answers.

Comment: ctrl+0 , to reset browser

Comment: Thank you! My head was hurting. Lol.

Comment: shortcut for most browsers: linux/win: `ctrl` + `0`, mac: `cmd` + `0`

Comment: almost pulled my hair   so many things to keep track of as a developer

Comment: That's half of the problem I have with HTML and CSS

Comment: Thank you so much dude!!

Comment: Man you just saved my life..

Answer (score 15):

Try this method.

> This will target based on device

```
@media screen 
 and (max-device-width: 1400px) 
 and (min-device-width: 480px) 
{ 
   .heading-left {
    left: -0.5%;
   }

}
```

> To target based on browser window area

```
@media screen 
 and (max-width: 1400px) 
 and (min-width: 480px) 
{ 
   .heading-left {
    left: -0.5%;
   }

}
```

Comment: Not working. max-device-width will check the width of the device and not the window right?

Comment: @DivyaBarsode, Yes, Try `max-width` if you want to target display browser.

Comment: @DivyaBarsode, edited my answer, added `max-width`. Its works fine in my local machine.

Comment: @DivyaBarsode, Can you try by adding `!important` to left property like  `left:-0.5% !important;` .

Comment: I just checked on opera browser.. It works fine there. But in chrome it isnt

Comment: @DivyaBarsode, Might be cache issue. @media should work fine on both browsers. Try `CTRL +F5` on your chrome and see the results, if still doesn't work then go through this link  
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30197932/cant-see-css-style-changes-in-browser/30198600#30198600

Comment: Did that before only but didnt work. In dev tools Elements tab, It doesnt show the media query. But when i go to dev tools-> Source -> css it shows the media query written

Answer (score 12):

You need to place the @media queries after you declare your standard

Comment: Thank you. This was my actual problem, and pretty sneaky if you you're not an experienced developer.

Answer (score 11):

Another thing that can happen is that you do something really stupid like:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1400)  { ... }
```

Make sure you put the px to identify what the quantity of your max-width is.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1400px)  { ... }
```

Not that I've ever been stuck for an hour on something so simple..

Comment: Ugh. This was my error. Thank you fine sir.

Answer (score 9):

This problem caused me several hours to figure it out with Bootstrap 3 when it just doesn't work. The reason is in the header of each web page, it needs this meta view element.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

More details https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me

```
@media screen and (max-width: 700px) and (min-width: 400px) { 
    .heading-left { left: -0.5%; }
}
```

Comment: I've forgot a space after `and` . Edited

Comment: max should be after min... Even though it's non-recommended trick.

Answer (score 4):

If you've tried everything and you're still stuck, remember that media queries need to be at the bottom because CSS is applied from top-down.

If you have

```
.container {
  color: white;
}
```

and you want the font to be pink for screens less than 600px wide, your other media query needs to be below the original .container style.

```
.container {
  color: white;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .container {
    color: pink;
  }
}
```

So if your media queries are at the top the default colour of white will override the media query for pink.

Answer (score 2):

Set these in your head tag

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
  /*Don't forget to add meta viewport in your html*/
}
```

If it's not working try to inspect elements in the browser by navigating to the network in developer tools and toggling disable cache.

Sometimes it's not working because of the browser cache.

Answer (score 0):

There is one thing I would like to add here, which is only applicable if you have different CSS files. If some values do not seem to be having any effect then check if the CSS file that has the media queries is at the bottom inside the  element or not. It is best to always put the media queries CSS file (if made in a different file) at the bottom of all other CSS links.